# Why does phpmyadmin shows only the title of my columns (but not the content of the column) when I make a union all?

Tags: mysql, sql

So my request is

```
SELECT 'titre', 'etat_du_stock' FROM `table1` 
UNION ALL SELECT 'titre', 'etat_du_stock' FROM table2
```

What I'm trying to do is show the content of two tables that contains the same columns (ID, titre, etat du stock, prix). I don't have any foreign keys so I thought a union all would actually show me the content of both tables to compare the data. However, whenever I type in my request in phpmyadmin, I end up having content of my tables all filled with the name of the columns and no data. [Here is the request I typed and the results I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nn8MT.jpg).

To be more specific, my boss is asking me to compare data of products from his data scraping. One table would be an old one and the new table would contain the new data (potentially new price, product unavailable etc). So basically the goal would be for him to compare both tables so he knows if the products have the same prices or did it change? And to know if the products are currently available or not? (hence the comparison between the 2 tables).
If somebody could explain how to fix my issue, I would be very thankful.

Comment: remove single quotes, you are printing strings instead of fields names

Answer (score 0):

Remove single quotes, you are printing strings instead of fields names

```
SELECT titre, etat_du_stock FROM table1 
UNION ALL 
SELECT titre, etat_du_stock FROM table2
```

You can add a string to verify from which table the data row came for easy comparison.

```
SELECT 'table1' as origin, titre, etat_du_stock FROM table1 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'table2 ', titre, etat_du_stock FROM table2
```